# Tax report doesn't show me the taxes right taxes

Tags: magento-1.9, tax

I have a problem with my Tax report. I need to view the exactly taxes from one day or month but it seems not to work.

For example: On 28. September I made three invoices. All together has the tax sum of 54,91€. It's split in 13% tax: 49,41€ and 20% tax: 5,5€

When I display my tax report it shows me different amounts but I never get my 54,91€.

The only report that seems to work anyway, is the invoiced report (Total Invoiced vs. Paid Report) with this options:
Match Period To: Last invoice created date
order status: any

With this report I see three invoices with the correct sum.

Is there a way to set up the tax report as i need it or is there an extension?

my Magento version is 1.9.2.1